# Bacnet4j COV subscription

Tags: java, bacnet, bacnet4j

I'm working with bacnet via java, the bacnet4j project. I have a device with bacnet objects and I want to monitor this object by second devices (COV). How can i run subscripton?

I should take advantage of
`localDevice.getEventHandler().addListener(new DeviceEventListener() {`
and use the functions that are there?

Maybe someone put me on the right track. Or is there any example I can analyze?

Comment: Can you clarify which side of communication you are - a subscription client who wants to get notified or subscription host who should send notifications?

Comment: I want to receive a notification and process it, but I don't know where the notification is from other devices

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this with real device (I authored [bacnet4j-wrapper](https://github.com/code-house/bacnet4j-wrapper) for subset of BACnet objects).

The change of value is two step process. First you need to add `DeviceEventListener`, just as you did. A more convenient way is `DeviceEventAdapter` which ships all methods - one you need to implement is `covNotificationReceived`.
Once you have your listener in place you need to fire `SubscribeCOVRequest` for specific object you want to watch.

Take a look on sources [ChangeOfValueTest.java](https://github.com/infiniteautomation/BACnet4J/blob/master/src/test/java/com/serotonin/bacnet4j/obj/ChangeOfValueTest.java#L114).

Comment: I get this message after trying to resubscribe from another device
[BACnet4J transport for device 98] WARN com.serotonin.bacnet4j.service.unconfirmed.UnconfirmedPrivateTransferRequest - No handler found for vendorId 8, serviceNumber 1, ignoring unconfirmed private transfer

Comment: Log entry you have is a remote request. I am not sure if these are correlated, are you sure your subscription request leaves your node and goes along the way? Please check with wireshark to confirm behavior.
You can also try reading remote device subscriptions to see if was accepted by destination. Try with `PropertyIdentifier.activeCovSubscriptions`. Some devices have limit of active subscribers.

Comment: I had some time to look at it. I send SubscribeCOVPropertyRequest with VTS program. In BACnet4J I see this request in requestReceived (not in covNotificationReceived). VTS program ireturns information about the error as if BACnet4J was unable to handle this query. I do not know how to activate the option of sending values ​​to the device that requested it.

Comment: Log: E / BACnet: requestReceived address: Address [networkNumber = 0, macAddress = [a, 1, a, f, ba, c0]] | 10.1.10.15:47808 service: Encodable (com.serotonin.bacnet4j.service.confirmed.SubscribeCOVPropertyRequest) ChoiceId (): 28 getNetworkPriority (): null.